# Let $f_n(x) = nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n$, $x\in (0, 1)$. Then $\int_{(0, 1)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n \neq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{(0, 1)}f_n.$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm learning about measure theory, specifically Lebesgue integration, and need help to understand the solution to the following problem:

Let $f_n(x) = nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n$, $x\in (0, 1)$. Show that

$$\int_{(0, 1)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n \neq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{(0, 1)}f_n.$$

> **Solution.** Obviously $\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x) = 1}_{(1)}$ and therefore $\int_{(0, 1)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n=1$.
>
> On the other hand, $\underbrace{\int_{(0, 1)}f_n=0}_{(2)}$, $n=1, 2, \cdots$.

It is not obvious to me that the sum $(1)$ is equal to one. Neither is it obvious that the Lebesgue integral $(2)$ is equal to zero for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm looking for an explanation that would help me understand both $(1)$ and $(2)$.

---

**Edit:** Considering the hint of **Zachary Selk** for $(2)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{(0,1)}f_n &= \int_{(0,1)}nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n\\
&= \int_{(0,1)}nx^{n-1}-\int_{(0,1)}(n+1)x^n\\
&= \left[\frac{nx^n}{n}\right]_{0}^{1}-\left[\frac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= (1^n-0^n)-(1^{n+1}-0^{n+1})\\
&= 1-1\\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Have you actually tried to calculate the integral (2)? As for (1), it is a telescoping sum...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 1, just note that it's a telescoping sum. That is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^k (nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n) =(1x^{1-1}-(1+1)x^1)+\cdots+(kx^{k-1}-(k+1)x^k)=1-(k+1)x^k$$

Just take the limit as $k \to \infty$ and you get $1$

For 2, just do the integral, The antiderivative is just the power rule.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I have edited my post with a complete answer for $(2)$. Could you tell me if my work is correct? Also, I have computed the integral like a Riemann integral. If the Riemann integral exists and is equal to zero, then the Lebesgue integral is equal to the Riemann integral. Is this the right way to conclude here?

Comment: @VonKar That is exactly correct.